# Segmentation fault while trying to use malloc

Tags: c, arrays, dynamic, struct, malloc

So, I have this struct.

```
typedef struct queue {
    int size; //size of the array
    int inicio; //first position that contains a value in the array
    int tamanho; //number of actual values in the array
    int *valores; //array
  } QUEUE;
```

And I have this function working with this struct

```
int enqueue (QUEUE *q, int x){
  if(q -> inicio + q -> tamanho < q -> size){
    q -> valores[q -> inicio + q -> tamanho] = x;
    q -> tamanho++;
  }

  else if (q -> tamanho < q -> size){
    for(int i = 0; i < q -> tamanho; i++){
      q -> valores[i] = q -> valores[q -> inicio + i];
    }
    q -> inicio = 0;
    q -> valores[q -> tamanho++] = x;
  }

  else{
    int *new = malloc(q -> size * 2 * sizeof(int));

    for(int i = 0; i < q -> size; i++){
      new[i] = q -> valores[i];
    }

    new[q -> size] = x;
    q -> size *= 2;
    free(q -> valores);
    q -> valores = new;
  }

  return 0;
}
```

When you take elements of the list, you take them from the beggining, so theres "nothing" in the beggining.

So this function is supposed to add the value to the end if it has space, to push everything to the beggining and add it in the end if it has empty space in the beggining and none in the end, and to expand the array if it needs more space. The thing is... It immediatly gives out a segmentation fault. If I try to print something right at the beggining of the else, it doesnt do it.

I am really lost.

Comment: In `q -> valores[q -> inicio + q -> tamanho] = x;` `valores` is pointer member of structure, have you allocated memory for `q->valores` ? I don't think so.

Comment: The problem isnt there. That bit works. q is an argument, its already initialized. the problem is somewhere in the third else. The first two work

Comment: show us how are you calling `enqueue()` with parameters

Comment: Sidenote: While there is no commonly accepted naming standard in C, all-uppercase names are expected to be macros. Don't use them for types, variables, etc.

Comment: QUEUE q1;
  q1.size = 3;
  q1.inicio = 0;
  q1.tamanho = 0;  

enqueue(&q1, 1); 

  enqueue(&q1, 2); 

  enqueue(&q1, 3); 

  enqueue(&q1, 4);

It works up until the last one

Comment: Olaf, this is an exercise from school... The teachers made it like this

Comment: I'm stupid... You're right achal, thank you very much

Comment: Hmmm, where do I change the state to solved?

Answer (score 0):

In `enqueue()` function allocate memory for `q -> valores`. Allocate it.

```
int enqueue (QUEUE *q, int x){
     q -> valores = malloc(sizeof(QUEUE));/*check yourself how much memory you need */

    /* remaining same code */
}
```